# solr suggester not returning any results

Tags: solr, spell-checking, autosuggest

I've followed the solr wiki article for suggester almost to the T here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester.  I have the following xml in my solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest"> 
     <lst name="spellchecker"> 
     <str name="name">suggest</str> 
     <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str> 
     <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str> 
     <str name="field">description</str> 
     <float name="threshold">0.05</float> 
     <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str> 
   </lst> 
</searchComponent> 
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest"> 
   <lst name="defaults"> 
     <str name="spellcheck">true</str> 
     <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str> 
     <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str> 
     <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str> 
     <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str> 
   </lst> 
   <arr name="components"> 
     <str>suggest</str> 
   </arr> 
</requestHandler>
```

However, when I run the following query (or something similar):

```
../suggest/?q=barbequ
```

I only get the following result xml back:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">78</int>
   </lst>
   <lst name="spellcheck">
      <lst name="suggestions"/>
   </lst>
</response>
```

As you can see, this isn't very helpful.  Any suggestions to help resolve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A couple of things I can think of that might cause this problem:

- The source field ("description") is incorrect - ensure that this is indeed the field that seeds terms for your spell checker.  It could even be that the field is a different case (eg. "Description" instead of "description").
- The source field in your schema.xml is not set up correctly or is being processed by filters that cause the source dictionary to be invalid.  I use a separate field to seed the dictionary, and use `<copyfield />` to copy relevant other fields to that.
- The term "barbeque" doesn't appear in at least 5% of records (you've indicated this requirement by including `<float name="threshold">0.05</float>`) and therefore is not included in the lookup dictionary
- In SpellCheckComponent the `<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>` setting means that only terms that would produce more results are returned as suggestions.  According to the Suggester documentation this has a different function (sorting suggestions by weight) but it might be worth switching this to false to see if it is causing the issue.

Relevant parts of my schema.xml:

```
<schema>
    <types>
        <!-- Field type specifically for spell checking -->
        <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    </fields>

    <!-- Copy fields which are used to seed the spell checker -->
    <copyField source="name" dest="spell" />
    <copyField source="description" dest="spell" />
<schema>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this:

According to the Suggester documentation this has a different function (sorting suggestions by weight) but it might be worth switching this to false to see if it is causing the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Could the problem be that you're querying `/suggest` instead of `/spell`

`../suggest/?q=barbequ`

In my setup this the string I pass in:

`/solr/spell?q=barbequ&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true`

And the first time you do a spellcheck you need to include

`&spellcheck.build=true`

I'm running on solr 4 btw.  So, perhaps /suggest is an entirely different endpoint that does something else.  If so, apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Please check, if the term-parameter are set in the schema.xml, like:

```
<field name="TEXT" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" 
                   termVectors="true"
                   termPositions="true"
                   termOffsets="true"/>
```

...restart solr and reindex again

Comment: I added termVectors="true", termPositions="true" and termOffsets="true" to my existing term-parameter (everything else was the same) yet it is still return the same result as above.

Comment: Have you restarted and re-indexed? Are you sure, that your field-type definition does not overwrite those settings? Probably there are relay no suggestions?

Comment: yeah, I restarted and re-indexed.  I don't believe it's being overwritten.  I know there's ton's of products that get returned perfectly with the /select query.  Is there a way to double check that the suggestions are there?  Also, I just tried incorporating this spellchecker method too: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent.  Same thing - no results returned in the spellcheck node.

Comment: @TheBndr Could you explain why term-paramaters are required? I don't think this is correct. Thanks

Comment: @TheBndr I would also like to know why term parameters are required? As I am also facing similar issue.