# Solr - Suggester not returning any suggestiions

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I'm trying to setup the [Solr suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) module.

I've followed the [guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) and setup my core as such:

solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
   <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
      <str name="field">city</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
      <float name="threshold">0</float>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>  
   </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

schema.xml

```
<types>

   <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSpell" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   </fieldType>

   </types>

   <fields>
       <!--  my other fieldsfields -->

       <field name="city" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   </fields>
```

and then rebuild the spellcheck with:

```
http://localhost:4569/solr/myCore/suggest?q=a&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

and then do a search:

```
http://localhost:4569/solr/myCore/suggest?q=aberdean&spellcheck=true&spellcheck=on
```

but I always get an empty suggestions in the response:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions"/>
    </lst>
 </response>
```

I've checked the suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653186/solr-suggester-not-returning-any-results)

Any idea why I'm not getting results?

Answer (score 0):

Can you **commit** and try your query? I guess it's because of the

```
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
```

Can you try again making it false.