# How to tune apache SOLR spellcheck for desired suggestion?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, spell-checking

***Enviroment: SAP Hybris 6.7.0.0, Apache Solr 7.7.2***

I am using solr to power a indie eCommerce platform. In that context we have product data in the Solr dB. For example: productName_text, BrandName_string, etc.

I've created a spellcheck component with this current configuration below:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">en</str>
            <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
            <str name="field">spellcheck_en</str>
            <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
            <float name="accuracy">0.7</float>
            <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
            <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
            <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
            <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
        </lst>
        </searchComponent>
```

And turned on spellcheck on `/select` request handler

```
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
            
        
        and spellcheck is configured  dynamically for the a single field. Suppose:
```

> productName_text

which consists of product names from a typical electronic gadgets or it's cases. For example:

> "Apple Watch Series 2 38mm Stainless Steel Case with Midnight Blue Modern Buckle Medium"
> "A.O. Smith X4 RO Water Purifier (White)"

*If we misspell "wath" for "watch" we get suggestion "water". Or spelling "suop maker" for "soup maker" we get "shop maker". How to tune spellchecker according to my data? Is there any other solution to implement for misbehaving queries.*

> Tried playing with all the spellcheck configuration from  [1]: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/SpellCheckComponent but couldn't find any solid solution yet.

> Tried implementing WordBreakSolrSpellChecker, which doesn't seem to change any outcome

> Played around with "spellcheck.collate" and other attributes, but it returns suggestion which has no search result.

> I've observed, spellcheck is deeply affected by multivalued fields(?)

In general, How to go about the terms which should give wrong suggestion, or suggestions that are that must not come based on user preferences? Is it possible to handle two different spellcheck components, if "DirectSolrSpellChecker" does'nt give desired suggestion , I can switch to "FilebasedSpellChecker"? Can I maintain a `.txt` file to track all the terms which needs tuning, or the same in SAP hybris?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [solr suggester not returning any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653186/solr-suggester-not-returning-any-results)

Comment: No, but if you can share,  what do you do when the spellchecker gives wrong suggestions?